# How to ensure SSD is healthy?

Tags: ssd, smart, diagnostic

I have heard that SSDs have shorter lifetime, than normal HDDs. And last time I have a suspicion, my SSD came to it's end. Symptoms include unexplainable BSODs, and program disappearing.

How could I ensure, that SSD is ok or not?

SMART gives no any signs:

[image]

Comment: That SSD has an endurance rating of 80 TB of writes and you have almost 73. It is definately reaching then end of its rated lifespan.

Comment: How do you know that (80Tb)?

Comment: Endurance statistics pulled from a review on [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8170/sandisk-extreme-pro-240gb-480gb-960gb-review). SanDisk doesn't post that information on their product page.

Comment: Is it possible to find SSD with higher endurance and how?

Comment: How full is this disk - if is too full, there is no enough space for relocating the blocks? Maybe you have to disable auto defrag in Windows - it is killing the disk unnecessarily . Also what is memory usage - if you are low on memory it pages to the disk more frequently. Figure out which are the most disk active apps (writing mostly).

Comment: Drive has approx 20 Gb free, page file is not located on it, and I have 32Gb of RAM

Comment: Wow, according to these values, I wrote at a speed of 7 gigabytes each hour!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That SSD has an endurance [rating](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8170/sandisk-extreme-pro-240gb-480gb-960gb-review) of 80 TB of writes and you have almost 73. It is definitely reaching then end of its rated lifespan.

Even with TRIM, that is a large amount of writing especially since the drive has a 10 year warranty (Meaning they don't expect you to write that much within that timeframe).

To answer the question about SSDs with higher endurance, there are more "write-oriented" drives and improvements to flash technology is constantly improving lifespans. However, it seems the issue here is an over-use of the SSD. Typically people put the OS and a select few programs with long loading times on the SSD, and everything else on slower mechanical disks. This lessens the amount of writing it has to do.

As a comparison, my SSD has a power on hour count on 5204 (I've had it in use almost every day for almost year) but only 5 TB of writes (Most were before I redirected my AppData folder to my NAS homefolder).

Comment: This drive was a system drive in a home computer, only operating system was on it. Pagefile, internet cache and My Documents were on other drive. How could I reach such value?